# Filling a matrix with 0's -1's and 1's with certain rules, what matrices occur?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Let $M$ be an $n\times m$ matrix with the following properties:

1. Every entry is either $0$,$-1$ or $1$.
2. Every column/row has at least one non-zero entry.
3. The last non-zero entry in each column/row is equal to $1$.
4. If the first non-zero entry in a column/row is equal to $1$, all other entries of the column/row must be equal to $0$.

What matrices $M$ do exist? Can we classify them somehow? Are there inductive properties of such matrices? What happens if $m=n$? Basically the more I know about such matrices the better :)

EDIT: Here are some examples:

For $n=1$ the consider the first entry of the first (and only) row. It must be equal to $1$ since it is the last entry of the first column. But then the rest of the first row must be equal to $0$. If $m>1$ it would follow that the seccond column has only zero entries, which is not allowed. Thus $m=1$ and the only matrix we obtain ist $(1)$.

For $n=2, m=2$ we find the following matrices:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

For $n>2, m=2$ (and similar for $n=2, m>2$) we find only one matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1& \dots & 1\\ 1 & 0 & \dots & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

For $n=3, m=3$ we find the following matrices:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} c & d & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} e & 1 & 0\\ f & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} g & h & 1\\ i & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

with $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,i=0,-1$ so $22$ in total.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us more. Write down all the examples for $n=1$ and $2$ and maybe $3$. Your condition 4 is ambiguous. I think you mean that each leading $1$ in a row has $0$ elsewhere its column. What you say seems to suggest all other row and column entries are $0$. If you can tell us where the problem comes from we may be able to help more. Just "tell everything you know" is rather loose.

Comment: I will edit it. What is meant by (4) is the following. If the first non-zero entry of a row is equal to 1, then all other entris of THIS row must be equal to zero. Similar for columns